# Windows 2008 Failover Cluster AD settings

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, failovercluster

I have two servers: serverA and serverB. 
They can see the same SAN disks: a 4 and a 400 GByte one. 
I created the Failover cluster on them, but the cluster says an error:

```
Cluster network name resource 'Cluster Name' failed registration of one or more associated DNS name(s) for the following reason:
DNS operation refused.

Ensure that the network adapters associated with dependent IP address resources are configured with at least one accessible DNS server.
```

AFAIK this is related that the object for ServerA and ServerB in the AD doesn't have permission for the Cluster object in the AD.

Question: What permission and how can I give in the AD to resolve this error message?

Answer (score 2):

It's an error 1196? Doublecheck that you have set the DNS server adresses right in every networks you have. I had this issue once, cause one of the networks had a different DNS adress, and pushed these errors every half an hour.

Comment: it is 1196, yes. 2 NIC: 1 for accessing the machine, 1 for heartbeat. I set the nameserver for the heartbeat too, but didn't helped. I think it is an AD related issue. It is in the logs at every 15 minutes.